Issue with configuring gRPC in Envoy: health check doesn't work
I have 3 local grpc services with ports 50052, 50053,50054.
I only started 2 of them. I want envoy to detect the unstarted service and disconnect, but it doesn't.
I want the endpoint that envoy can monitor to hang up and stop forwarding traffic to the corresponding endpoint.
What should i do?
Here is the envoy configuration file:
static_resources:
  listeners:
  - name: grpc_listener
    address:
      socket_address:
        address: 0.0.0.0
        port_value: 5051 
    filter_chains:
    - filters:
      - name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
        typed_config:
          "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.http_connection_manager.v3.HttpConnectionManager
          codec_type: AUTO
          stat_prefix: grpc_proxy
          route_config:
            name: local_route
            virtual_hosts:
            - name: grpc_virtual_host
              domains:
              - "*" 
              routes:
              - match:
                  prefix: "/"  
                route:
                  cluster: grpc_cluster
          http_filters:
          - name: envoy.filters.http.router
            typed_config:
              "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.router.v3.Router
  clusters:
  - name: grpc_cluster
    connect_timeout: 1s  
    # type: STATIC
    type: STRICT_DNS
    lb_policy: ROUND_ROBIN  
    http2_protocol_options: {}
    load_assignment:
      cluster_name: grpc_cluster
      endpoints:
      - lb_endpoints:
        - endpoint:
            address:
              socket_address:
                address: 127.0.0.1
                port_value: 50052 
        - endpoint:
            address:
              socket_address:
                address: 127.0.0.1
                port_value: 50053 
        - endpoint:
            address:
              socket_address:
                address: 127.0.0.1
                port_value: 50054  
    health_checks:
    - timeout: 1s
      interval: 5s
      unhealthy_threshold: 1
      healthy_threshold: 3
      grpc_health_check: {}
      event_log_path: "/tmp/grpc_health_check.log"

    outlier_detection:
      consecutive_5xx: 2  
      interval: 10s       
      base_ejection_time: 30s  
    typed_extension_protocol_options:
      envoy.extensions.upstreams.http.v3.HttpProtocolOptions:
        "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.upstreams.http.v3.HttpProtocolOptions
        explicit_http_config:
          http2_protocol_options: {}  

Here is the health check log in /tmp/grpc_health_check.log:
{"health_checker_type":"GRPC","host":{"socket_address":{"protocol":"TCP","address":"127.0.0.1","port_value":50054,"resolver_name":"","ipv4_compat":false}},"cluster_name":"grpc_cluster","timestamp":"2024-12-16T07:34:39.843Z","health_check_failure_event":{"failure_type":"NETWORK","first_check":true},"metadata":{"filter_metadata":{},"typed_filter_metadata":{}},"locality":{"region":"","zone":"","sub_zone":""}}
{"health_checker_type":"GRPC","host":{"socket_address":{"protocol":"TCP","address":"127.0.0.1","port_value":50052,"resolver_name":"","ipv4_compat":false}},"cluster_name":"grpc_cluster","timestamp":"2024-12-16T07:34:39.852Z","health_check_failure_event":{"failure_type":"ACTIVE","first_check":true},"metadata":{"filter_metadata":{},"typed_filter_metadata":{}},"locality":{"region":"","zone":"","sub_zone":""}}
{"health_checker_type":"GRPC","host":{"socket_address":{"protocol":"TCP","address":"127.0.0.1","port_value":50053,"resolver_name":"","ipv4_compat":false}},"cluster_name":"grpc_cluster","timestamp":"2024-12-16T07:34:39.852Z","health_check_failure_event":{"failure_type":"ACTIVE","first_check":true},"metadata":{"filter_metadata":{},"typed_filter_metadata":{}},"locality":{"region":"","zone":"","sub_zone":""}}

